# How to fix a mobile modem that worked with Ubuntu 12.10 but doesn't with 13.04?

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, networking, usb-modem

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 and now I can not connect to my mobile internet service. It worked perfectly before but it no longer does with 13.04. I have a Huawei modem from the Paraguayan company Personal. It gets detected but it does not connect to the network. I tried it in other notebooks and it doesn't work there either. I was told that it is a problem with the new Ubuntu. How I can fix it. Thank you.
Model of modem USB
HUAWEI Model: E173s - 6

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did your modem worked in Ubuntu 12.10 just by plugging it in, or did you have to install or configure anything?

Comment: It worked just plug it. Upon plug-in version 13.04 recognizes and installs but does not connect.                                         Funcionó solo con enchufarlo. Al enchufarlo en la version 13.04 reconoce e instala pero no conecta.

Comment: Please provide more details (for example, the model of the modem) so the community can better help you. Edit your question and add the additional information (instead of answering in comments).

Comment: Also, check the following Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/q/217517/58950, http://askubuntu.com/q/211396/58950, perhaps they might help. Search around this website, starting with the links provided to the right, under "Related".

Answer (score 1):

Successfully connect my Huawei USB modem using sakis3g http://dc399.4shared.com/download/NAhY5Sle/sakis3g.gz?tsid=20130813-213724-6ed8994f
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Glad that your problem is solved. Please expand a little your answer so other users with similar problem can understand how this fixes it and consider if the solution applies to their particular case. If possible, also provide links to the source of the answer.

Comment: ... Also: mark the question as [answered](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer). Yes, you can [answer your own question and accept it as the correct one](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I could not use my USB Modem HUAWEI E173s - 6 PERSONAL PARARAGUAY telephony provider. I could connect to the application Sakis3g is a connections manager. It can be downloaded at the following link. http://dc399.4shared.com/download/NAhY5Sle/sakis3g.gz?tsid=20130813-213724-6ed8994f
They must have realized 4Shared